# Oracle Script To Loop Insert Statement 20 Times

Tags: java, sql, oracle11g, batch-processing

I have a requirement to insert 20 
(same) records when I send one insert query to oracle DB.

Something like this :

```
insert all 
into colors(name, category) values('yellow', 1) 
into colors(name, category) values('yellow', 1) 
into colors(name, category) values('yellow', 1) 
into colors(name, category) values('yellow', 1) 
into colors(name, category) values('yellow', 1) 
.
.
.
select * from dual;
```

But the problem with this statement is, I have to loop the same record twenty times programmatically which will impact the performance if I plan to insert 1 million records.

I am looking for a script to loop the insert statement at DB side but not at code side.

Please suggest...

Comment: are you thinking of batch insert?

Comment: From shell script you can easily do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert all 
into colors(name, category) values('yellow', 1) 
select * from dual connect by level <= 20;
```

or

```
insert into colors(name, category)  
select 'yellow', 1 from dual connect by level <= 20;
```